# Sql select sub query with count

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery

Ok so i have 3 tables :
`[AXprod].[dbo].[RMSPOSINVOICE]`,`[AXPROD].[dbo].[discountcard]` ,`[IntegrationProd].[dbo].[POS_KvitoGalva]`. And i want to find out when discount card was used more than once in one inventlocation and time when it was used. The table  `[IntegrationProd].[dbo].[POS_KvitoGalva]` has these times. I use this code to get the time each card was used each day is:

```
 sELECT a.discountcardid,count(a.discountcardid)
  FROM [AXprod].[dbo].[RMSPOSINVOICE] a
  inner join [AXPROD].[dbo].[discountcard] b
  on a.discountcardid = b.discountcardid
  inner join [IntegrationProd].[dbo].[POS_KvitoGalva] c
  on a.possalesid = c.id
   where a.dataareaid = 'ermi' and len(a.discountcardid) > '0' and b.dataareaid = 'ermi' and ('500' = a.inventlocationid )
 and (a.invoicedate >= '2015-04-22 00:00:00.000' and a.invoicedate <= '2015-04-22 00:00:00.000')
  group by a.discountcardid,a.inventlocationid,a.posnumber
   having count(a.discountcardid) > '1'
```

And i get the following result:

```
DISCOUNTCARDID COUNT
123456           2
145962           2
```

and i have a query to find when each card was used (date and time)

```
 SELECT a.discountcardid,a.inventlocationid,a.posnumber,year,month,day,hour,minute,c.id
FROM [AXprod].[dbo].[RMSPOSINVOICE] a
  inner join [AXPROD].[dbo].[discountcard] b
  on a.discountcardid = b.discountcardid
  inner join [IntegrationProd].[dbo].[POS_KvitoGalva] c
  on a.possalesid = c.id
   where a.dataareaid = 'ermi' and len(a.discountcardid) > '0' and b.dataareaid = 'ermi' and ('500' = a.inventlocationid )
 and (a.invoicedate >= '2015-04-22 00:00:00.000' and a.invoicedate <= '2015-04-22 00:00:00.000')
  group by a.discountcardid,a.inventlocationid,a.posnumber,year,month,day,hour,minute,c.id
   order by DISCOUNTCARDID
```

And i get the result:

```
discountcardid  inventlocationid    posnumber   year    month   day hour    minute  id
123456      500 7   2015    4   22  12  44  6355302
123456      500 7   2015    4   22  14  24  6355302
145962      500 7   2015    4   22  13  56  6355302
145962      500 7   2015    4   22  13  24  6355302
145555      500 7   2015    4   22  12  11  5465465
```

The problem:
I dont want to get discount cards that were only used once so i try this:

```
 SELECT a.discountcardid,a.inventlocationid,a.posnumber,year,month,day,hour,minute,c.id,
 ( sELECT count(s.discountcardid)
  FROM [AXprod].[dbo].[RMSPOSINVOICE] s
  inner join [AXPROD].[dbo].[discountcard] b
  on s.discountcardid = b.discountcardid
  inner join [IntegrationProd].[dbo].[POS_KvitoGalva] c
  on s.possalesid = c.id
   where s.dataareaid = 'ermi' and len(s.discountcardid) > '0' and b.dataareaid = 'ermi' and ('500' = s.inventlocationid )
 and (s.invoicedate >= '2015-04-22 00:00:00.000' and s.invoicedate <= '2015-04-22 00:00:00.000') and s.DISCOUNTCARDID = a.DISCOUNTCARDID 
  group by s.discountcardid,s.inventlocationid,s.posnumber
   having count(a.discountcardid) > '1')
FROM [AXprod].[dbo].[RMSPOSINVOICE] a
  inner join [AXPROD].[dbo].[discountcard] b
  on a.discountcardid = b.discountcardid
  inner join [IntegrationProd].[dbo].[POS_KvitoGalva] c
  on a.possalesid = c.id
   where a.dataareaid = 'ermi' and len(a.discountcardid) > '0' and b.dataareaid = 'ermi' and ('500' = a.inventlocationid )
 and (a.invoicedate >= '2015-04-22 00:00:00.000' and a.invoicedate <= '2015-04-22 00:00:00.000')
  group by a.discountcardid,a.inventlocationid,a.posnumber,year,month,day,hour,minute,c.id
   order by DISCOUNTCARDID
```

But all i get is the same number of values and NULL in the last field in all columns. I hope i made myself clear ;).

Comment: I'm sorry, but these SQL statements are very hard to read. If you format them better it would become easier for both you and us to find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to call the query once and use an windowed function in order to get the count. I don't believe you can use an analytic function in the where statement so I added an additional SELECT statement in order to add the WHERE > 1 for the count.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT 
    a.discountcardid,
    a.inventlocationid,
    a.posnumber,
    year,
    month,
    day,
    hour,
    minute,
    c.id,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY a.discountcardid, a.inventlocationid, a.posnumber) AS CardCount
FROM AXprod.dbo.RMSPOSINVOICE a
JOIN AXprod.dbo.discountcard b
    ON b.discountcardid = a.discountcardid
JOIN IntegrationProd.dbo.POS_KvitoGalva c
    ON c.id = a.possalesid
WHERE a.dataareaid = 'ermi' 
AND len(a.discountcardid) > '0' 
AND b.dataareaid = 'ermi' 
AND a.inventlocationid = 500
AND a.invoicedate >= '2015-04-22 00:00:00.000' 
AND a.invoicedate <= '2015-04-22 00:00:00.000'
) d
WHERE d.CardCount > 1
ORDER BY d.discountcardid
```

Comment: Works great! Can you explain what does this statement mean?  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY a.discountcardid, a.inventlocationid, a.posnumber) AS CardCount

Comment: It's a window function, which allows you to use functions (MAX, COUNT, SUM, etc.) for each row without using a GROUP BY. The portion that is in PARTITION BY is basically the GROUP BY in this case but you don't have to limit the rest of the selected columns to the GROUP BY columns as you normally would. In this example, the COUNT is counting the number of times the exact grouping of discountcardid, inventlocationid, and posnumber occur. simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/window-functions-in-sql –